# Live Edit not working Android Studio Electric Eel

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying out the Canary version of Android Studio, Electric Eel. Live Edit isn't working (either the older version or the new Canary experimental version).

If I try the experimental version, when I launch my app and look at the top left of the editor, I see a check mark beside Live Edit, but hovering over it says "No apps are ready to receive live edits", then after trying an edit it changes to a red ! and says "Invalid installer response Application must be restarted." Restarting doesn't fix it.

If I try the older Live Edit of literals, the edits just don't do anything, and I can't see any kind of warnings.

Anyone have any ideas how I can fix it? The Live Edit of literals works fine on the same app on the stable Android Studio.

Comment: I use the latest Canary, per my knowledge, but I've never encountered such warnings/errors in the live edit panel. The edits don't do anything anymore, that's true, for me, but haven't seen anything that might help diagnose the problem, or to indicate officially that there is a problem at all. I was guessing that it might be just taking too long, and I chose not to wait for it. The thing is, it was working well before, but now the project has grown. Apparently it's struggling to process through the navigation system.

Comment: Check this : [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772547/android-studio-dolphin-2021-3-1-electric-eel-2022-1-1-does-not-show-la) and [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75160820/android-studio-electric-eel-2022-1-1-not-showing-previews)

Answer (score 0):

Live Edit is available in Android Studio Giraffe. To turn it on, navigate to File > Settings > Editor > Live Edit (Android Studio > Settings > Editor > Live Edit on macOS).
In the previous Flamingo version of Android Studio it's experimental feature.

Also 1 more thing-  In Android Studio Giraffe and higher it requires Jetpack Compose Runtime 1.3.0 or higher and AGP 8.1 or higher.