# Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 not showing Previews

Tags: android, android-studio

Just upgraded to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 i am unable to see any previews in my studio.

I have tried all possible ways but didn't find any solution for this. tried invalidated cache and restart , upgraded griddle version. tried changing the themes of screens. nothing worked .

any help ?

Answer (score 1):

It conflicts with material library. Don't use alpha version.

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0-alpha01'
```

to this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an known bug and i too faced the same issue.

Try installing the latest patch for Android Studio Electric Eel. It should fix the same.